# Formulation of the preservation theorem for typing relations

Tags: type-theory

In the book "Types and Programming Languages" by Pierce, the preservation theorem for a typing relation is written as

$$if\ t : T\ and\ t \rightarrow t',\ then\ t' : T$$

On the one hand, the book mentions that $t : T$ means that *t is well typed*, on the other hand - for the typing rule

$$\frac{t_1 : Bool\ t_2 : T\ t_3 : T}{if\ t_1\ then\ t_2\ else\ t_3:T}$$

- the book explicitly states that the metavariable T is used twice to indicate that the terms $t_2$ and $t_3$ have the same type.

The problem I have is that, in plain text, the authors explain the preservation theorem states that

> A well-typed term is still well-typed after it takes a step of evaluation.

This seems to conflict with my "translation" of the mathematical notation which is

> If a term with type T takes a step of evaluation, the resulting term is still of **the same** type T.

Hence my question: What is the meaning of the variable $T$ and the expression $t : T$ in the formal definition of the theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt there's a conflict here, though it's hard to tell without more context. The "formal" definition does state what you say it does, if a term of type $T$ reduces, the reduct has the same type $T$. This *implies* that a well-typed term reduces to a well-typed term. It is not equivalent to it (on its own), since one could imagine a well-typed term reducing to another well-typed term but with a different type. I don't believe the "plain text" explanation is meant to be a definition or a restating of the definition.